# Create a string of sequential numbers in an oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

Using oracle SQL I want to generate a string list of numbers counting up to a quantity value.

```
Select [Item], [Quantity], <Something here> as [Quantity List]
from table
```

to return

```
[Item],[Quantity], [Quantity List]
'Socks', 2 , '1 2'
'Shoes', 3 , '1 2 3'
'Coats', 6 , '1 2 3 4 5 6'
'Hats' , 3 , '1 2 3'   etc...
```

I'm not trying to create a reference table, each quantity needs to be evaluated and appropriate string put in as it runs
Thanks in advance

Comment: oracle or microsoft sql?

Comment: @Jim . . . Your question specifies Oracle, but you are using square braces which is confusing.  Those are usually associated with SQL Server (although Sybase and SQLite also support them).

Comment: sorry yes i'm a tsql person by trade, force of habit it is most certainly oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest generating all the numbers first and then joining in.  You can generate the list using a recursive CTE:

```
with cte(n, max_qty, list) as (
      select 1, max_qty, '1'  as list
      from (select max(quantity) as max_qty from t) x
      union all
      select n + 1, max_qty, list || ' ' || (n + 1) 
      from cte
      where n < max_qty
     )
select t.*, cte.list
from t join
     cte
     on t.quantity = cte.n;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f1b608f184d027e8cbeeca5e9d0a9303) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  If you really are using SQL Server, you can use very similar logic in that database.

Comment: Thanks Gordon that's great

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hiearchical query` in sub query of `select clause` as follows:

```
select item, quantity,
       (select listagg(level, ' ') within group(order by level)
         from dual connect by level <= quantity) as quantity_list
  from t
```

[Db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=112a44a12c5a03e3a140dd2b96a07fd3) for the same.